# symfony/yaml backed symfony/config not parsing environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, yaml, symfony-3.2

I have recreated a simple example [in this tiny github repo](https://github.com/zippy1981/symphony-dependency-env). I am attempting to use `symfony/dependency-injection` to configure `monolog/monolog` to write logs to `php://stderr`. I am using a yaml file called services.yml to configure dependency injection.

This all works fine if my yml file looks like this:

```
parameters:
    log.file: 'php://stderr'
    log.level: 'DEBUG'

services:
    stream_handler:
    class:     \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler
    arguments:
     - '%log.file%'
     - '%log.level%'
    log:
    class:     \Monolog\Logger
    arguments: [ 'default',  ['@stream_handler']  ]
```

However, my goal is to read the path of the log files and the log level from environment variables, `$APP_LOG` and `LOG_LEVEL` respectively. According to [The symphony documentations on external paramaters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html) the correct way to do that in the services.yml file is like this:

```
parameters:
    log.file: '%env(APP_LOG)%'
    log.level: '%env(LOGGING_LEVEL)%'
```

In my sample app I verified PHP can read these environment variables with the following:

```
echo "Hello World!\n\n";

echo 'APP_LOG=' . (getenv('APP_LOG') ?? '__NULL__') . "\n";
echo 'LOG_LEVEL=' . (getenv('LOG_LEVEL') ?? '__NULL__') . "\n";
```

Which writes the following to the browser when I use my original services.yml with hard coded values.:

```
Hello World!

APP_LOG=php://stderr
LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

However, if I use the %env(VAR_NAME)% syntax in services.yml, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "env_PATH_a61e1e48db268605210ee2286597d6fb" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array) #1 /var/www/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #2 /var/www/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(532): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(100, 'Initialized dep...', Array) #3 /var/www/html/index.php(17): Monolog\Logger->debug('Initialized dep...') #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `'%env(PATH)%'` is pretty much guaranteed to not be a valid file path. Why aren't you using `APP_LOG` and `LOG_LEVEL` in the yaml like you do in your PHP snippet?

Comment: @flyx I meant %env(APP_LOG)% I stuck PATH in there temporarly just to see if that resolved and apparently stuck it in my code. Originally it was APP_LOG. Verified that's not my problem.

Comment: So, your error now includes `env_APP_LOG_{hash}`?

Comment: @flyx yes it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok you need a few things here. First of all you need version 3.3 of Symfony, which is still in beta. 3.2 was the released version when I encountered this. Second you need to "compile" the environment variables.

Edit your `composer.json` with the following values and run `composer update`. You might need to update other dependencies. You can substitute `^3.3` with `dev-master`.

```
    "symfony/config": "^3.3",
    "symfony/console": "^3.3",
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "^3.3",
    "symfony/yaml": "^3.3",
```

You will likely have to do this for `symfony/__WHATEVER__` if you have other symfony components.

Now in you're code after you load your yaml configuration into your dependency container you compile it.

So after you're lines here (perhaps in bin/console):

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..'));
$loader->load('services.yml');
```

Do this:

> $container->compile(true);

Your IDE's intellisense might tell you compile takes no parameters. That's ok. That's because [compile() grabs its args indirectly](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/21460/commits/a3fd512271b05cf522111ec6fe1cce8e2f7eb784#diff-a10c9afd8feaccd1ff66ffd54e2835bcR667) via [func_get_arg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php).

```
public function compile(/*$resolveEnvPlaceholders = false*/)
{
    if (1 <= func_num_args()) {
        $resolveEnvPlaceholders = func_get_arg(0);
    } else {
    . . .
}
```

#### References

- [Github issue where this was discussed](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21420)
- [Pull request to add compile(true)](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/21460)

Answer (score 0):

Using this command after loading your `services.yaml` file should help.

`$containerBuilder->compile(true);`
given your files gets also validated by the checks for proper configurations which this method also does. The parameter is `$resolveEnvPlaceholders` which makes environmental variables accessible to the yaml services configuration.